# Constraint layout both horizontal and vertical chain

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Hi I am trying to make a Calculator app for demo at school with Android Constraint Layout chain attribute.

I chain the buttons on it both vertically and horizontally like so

[image: My current screen]

But I am having trouble setting the vertical weight of the "=" button ( the Test button in my example ) so that its height is equals to 2 other buttons height ( like the format on some calculator ).

Setting the vertical weight seems to does nothing, how can I address this problem please. I dont want to use another layout or setting the height programmatically.

Thanks

Comment: Post the code in order for us to see and be helpfully.

Comment: use `app:layout_constraintVertical_weight`

Comment: @cod-e-rection sorry I am new, I will do that from now on

Comment: @JakirHossain thanks, I found the answer

Answer (score 0):

Answer found, I just need to unset height so vertical_weight works